# Madgwick IMU 90 Degrees Angles

Tags: matlab, euler-angles

I'm using the C++ implementation of the Madgwick Algorithim, having my sensors (accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope) calibrated. Everything seems to work well, but when I put the sensor in vertical position (pitch to 90 degrees) the other angles start doing weird things. This is what I get:
[Matlab plot problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvgh.png)

In fact, the angles I get are correct, but expressed in a different way. I should get only:

- Roll: 0
- Pitch: 90
- Yaw: -150

But I get:

- Roll: -180
- Pitch: 90
- Yaw: 50

Both results are the same, right? My questions are:

- Is this the Gimbal Lock problem?
- As far as I know, Gimbal Lock should get errors in the angles, but I'm getting them OK. Is the Madgwick algorithm trying to avoid that Gimbal Lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not Gimbal lock a sensor, as it is a physical object that you moved.

Gimbal lock refers to a state on where if you where to move 2 angles, they would have the same effect on the rotation. It is not an error, but an specific rotation state. But if you are personally moving the object by hand, Gimbal lock is impossible. Wikipedia has a brilliant gif:

[image]

> Gimbal locked airplane. When the pitch (green) and yaw (magenta) gimbals become aligned, changes to roll (blue) and yaw apply the same rotation to the airplane.

However, note that the cause of Gimbal lock may be the cause of your data: In euler angles, there are multiple sets of angles that give the exact same end point. Which one does your system gives you? you cant know. Depends on the sensor and algorithm used to give you the data.

A good way of ensuring your further maths are consistent and knowing that 2 rotations are the same is to convert your measurements into quaternions. These are unique to every rotation, and will help you better understand what rotation has happened.